# Firestore read limits?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

On my "App Engine - Quotas" page, I see that I am making "Cloud Firestore Read Operations   - 1.11 Million Ops".

I am currently on the Flame plan, and I see it has a "Cloud Firestore - Document reads - 250K/day". Doesn't that mean I am way over the quota, and would be charged or something? I haven't seen anything indicating that I am over the quota.

Also with my queries, one such query goes into the database and pulls out 60 records. Does this count as one single "document read", or is this 60 documents since that is what the query is returning?

Comment: Did you make 1.11 million reads all in one day? If so, you're over the limit.

Comment: If I am over the limit, when would it warn me of that and then start charging me? I haven't seen anything like that yet.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to that as well.  As for your query question, that would count as 60 read operations.  You are charged based on the size of your result set.

Comment: Did you find the answer? On our project with Flame plan we also see Firestore reads way over the daily quota, but no warning or any other noticeable limitation. Is that a bug in Firebase quota calculation or restriction rule or something else?